# Bind9 performance issues with Docker containers

Tags: 18.04, docker, dyndns

We are running a service that is hosted through some Docker containers on a server. The applications in these containers make some very frequent requests to a local cluster of around 300 machines. There are two local DNS severs (primary and secondary) running bind9, hosting the zone files for local machines. 
It seems the primary server is not able to handle the load and some DNS queries seem to be timing out and spilling over to the secondary server. On the secondary server we see a constant slow stream of queries in the querylog.

I have tried to increase the number of threads on the primary server which did not seem to help.
There is no DNS caching in the Docker containers and we are trying to avoid touching the Docker images to add any caching mechanism.
The DNS server is running on two six-core processors with 64GB of RAM. Hardware does not seem to be the bottleneck here. We are wondering if there is an obvious tuning parameter that we are missing for bind.

We are running Ubuntu Linux 18.04 all across.

Bind version: `BIND 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.9-Ubuntu (Extended Support Version) <id:a375815>`

named.conf.options:

```
    options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
       forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };
        dnssec-validation auto;
        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

Comment: Which version of bind are you running ? can you provide the options section of `named.conf` ?

Comment: Sorry @Fractalyse, I should have added that to the question. It's there now. thanks

Comment: Why avoiding cache ?

Comment: So we see couple of options. Either run a dedicated `dnsmasq` container on Docker server or add `dmsmasq` to every single container. Current Docker images are minimal and we prefer keeping them as such. By making changes we might introduce overheads leading to other performance issues. Also we end up adding to the list of things to worry about when adding new Docker images or modifying existing ones.
If DNS server could just take the load then it might be a cleaner solution? In truth we don't know. Should we consider something totally different? CoreDNS?

Comment: You can enable caching in bind9 using `allow-query-cache` in the option section of `named.conf`, afaik `dnsmasq` is not design to handle hundreds of hosts. Imo running `dnsmasq` on each container is not worth it. As speficied [here](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00463) options `clients-per-query` and `max-clients-per-query` will drop queries if too many clients ask for same name/type at the same time, by default  `clients-per-query`  is set to 10 and `max-clients-per-query` is set to 100, this could be another bottleneck for you.

Comment: `allow-query-cache` is probably not relevant here as this server is authoritative for most of the queries. I upped `clients-per-query` and `max-clients-per-query` to 100 and 500 respectively without any change in behavior. I am also exploring tuning Linux network parameters (sysctl values). Will post here if I find anything. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I completed my investigation and found a satisfactory answer for the behavior that we were observing in our environment. When I noticed DNS queries on the secondary DNS server, I assumed the primary DNS server to be having performance issues. And I kept digging with this assumption and kept on trying to improve perfomance or find problems with primary server.

But after my digging I have found that the way systemd-resolved works is, it would switch the DNS servers as soon as there is a delay/hiccup on the "current" server. And then it would stick with the newer server until there is a hiccup and then rotate back to original server again. This traffic being UDP and with this high number of requests and clients, there are many chances of dropped packets and servers keep getting rotated. This does not seem to be causing much performance issue and actually end up spreading load across multiple servers. So I am leaving it at that.

Though there is a heated discussion regarding this behavior in systemd github: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5755

Also during my digging while trying to get better performance for my BIND servers I came across some resources that might be handy:

- https://gist.github.com/voluntas/bc54c60aaa7ad6856e6f6a928b79ab6c
- https://community.akamai.com/customers/s/article/DNS-at-1-000-000-tps-and-Beyond?language=en_US